# What is the difference between clicked and pressed in Qt?

Tags: qt, user-interface, mouseclick-event, mousepress

How do I distinguish between `Clicked` and `Pressed`?

What does `Released` mean?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

- **Pressed**: event is generated when you push down the mouse button
- **Released**: event is generated when you release the mouse button (*which has been pressed down before*)
- **Clicked**: event is generated when a mouse button *Pressed* & *Released*.

With these functions you can create a snap-switch for example:

***when you press*** the button, the light will switch off / the music stop / etc , **when you release** it, light switches back on / the music starts again etc.

Answer (score 8):

Clicked is a complete click (press and release), released is when you let go of the mouse button and pressed is when you press down on your mouse button.